# Android compose passing function into composable

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to learn compose and am in the process of switching over a toolbar to using it but I am struggling with understanding how to pass a function.

Data class

```
data class ToolbarData(
    val closeClick: (() -> Unit)? = null,
    val title: Int,
    val completeClick: (() -> Unit)? = null
)
```

Composable

```
@Composable
fun ComposeToolBar(toolbarData: ToolbarData) {
    Row(verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically) {
        Image(
            painter = painterResource(id = drawable.ic_close),
            contentDescription = stringResource(id = R.string.close_descrption),
            Modifier.clickable { toolbarData.closeClick?.invoke() }
        )
        Text(text = stringResource(id = toolbarData.title))
        Image(
            painter = painterResource(id = drawable.ic_check),
            contentDescription = stringResource(id = R.string.complete_descrption)
        )
    }
}
```

and preview function

```
@Preview
@Composable
fun PreviewToolbar() {
    ComposeToolBar(toolbarData = ToolbarData(title = R.string.app_name))
}
```

If I remove

```
Modifier.clickable { toolbarData.closeClick?.invoke() }
```

builds just fine and with it being nullable or non nullable I get the error.

org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.BackendException: Backend Internal error: Exception during IR lowering
File being compiled: /path
The root cause java.lang.NullPointerException was thrown at: org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.lower.inlineclasses.InlineClassAbi.getUnderlyingType(InlineClassAbi.kt:61)

Comment: this code builds fine to me. problem most probably is related to your dependencies, check that everything is up to date, create a new empty project to see it works. If none of this helps, create a sample project where it can be reproduced

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out I left out the below when I was adding it to my project.

```
composeOptions {
    kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.0.1"
}
```